# How do I populate the class list which has list of classes for each class item with MySQL data?

Tags: c#, mysql, list, class

This is one of the classes I have in C# :

```
public class Courses
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string SchoolName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string MajorName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<string> Course { get; set; }

        public Courses()
        {
            Course = new List<string>();
        }
    }
```

For each Major, there is a list of classes.

In my database, I have three tables for school, major and courses joined with foreign leys. A simple SQL table to read them would be for a given school :

```
SELECT 
major.MajorName,
course.CourseName 
FROM school
INNER JOIN major ON major.MajorID = course.MajorID  
WHERE school.SchoolName = @SchoolName AND major.SchoolNameID = school.SchoolNameID GROUP BY major.MajorName;
```

So based on this, I expect the data as follows.
(Multiple major names and each major with multiple courses)

```
MajorName   CourseName
Science      SC101
Science      SC102
Science      SC500
Math         MA100
Math         MA200
ENGLISH      EN450
```

What is the best way I could populate the class I derived at the beginning?
My class definision inside database read query would be :

```
List<Courses> majorclasses = new List<Courses>()
```

I could manual manage the data to populate the class by reading distinct majorNames and then populating each course for each majorName in a loop.

```
(pheudo code)
List<string> distinctMajors = majorClasses.Disticnt("majorNames").ToList()
foreach major in distinctMajors
{
   course.Add(courseName)
}
```

Any other better method to acheive this ?

Comment: It would be simpler if you adjusted your original sql query to display in the manner you want.

Comment: Your foreach loop seems to duplicate the LINQ immediately above it. It only makes sense if `course` already contains information.

Comment: Btw, how are you reading your queries result? SqlDataReader?

Comment: Hi SILENT 1: What is the best way to read the SQL table to populate my class ? I want to read list of lists but I dont know how to do that in SQL. Any help ?

Comment: Yes, I am reading with SQLdataReader.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
List<Courses> courses =  data.GroupBy(
    d => new { d.SchoolName, d.MajorName},
    d => d.CourseName,
    (key,g) => new Courses {
        MajorName = key.MajorName,
        SchoolName = key.SchoolName,
        Course = g.Distinct().ToList() }
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: I like this method but not familiar with it. What "data" here ? MySQLDataReader record ?

Comment: data is the result of your query result. But if you have DataReader you should get the data and convert it to list before. your list items should have SchoolName, MajorName and CourseName elements.

Comment: Got it. This is cute method that have not came across , I will play with it